# Aligning an img left in a div tag?

Tags: html, css

EDIT: This might make more sense, check this image. http://puu.sh/rt8M
The image just goes through the padding. I want the title div to expand vertically to accommodate the image. While keeping the text centered and the center of the image should intersect the line the text is on.

---

---

I want to align an img to the left (and then another after the text to the right). I've tried various properties but none seem to do it right. Can anyone help?

To clarify, I want the image against the left side of the screen or browser window. The div stretches from the left to the right of screen, as you would expect of a header/title div.

Float;left seems to make the img drop out of the div tag. I should mention there is a text-align:center; property on the  tag. But it doesn't fix the problem when removed so I'm not sure it's that.

The HTML

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="title">
    <h1>
    <img class="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="" width="86" height="98" />
    <a href="index.html">Page Header Title</a>
    </h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The image should go to the left, but where should the text go? To the right?

Comment: may be i misinterpret your question, but i think you want your logo on most left side of the browser is it so then you need to set left margin with -ve value, like that:http://jsfiddle.net/BvCGh/

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<div id="header" style="float:left">
<div id="title">
<h1>
<img class="logo" src="images/logo.png" width="86" height="98" />
<a href="index.html">Page Header Title</a>
</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a little dabblet code example for you. I think this is what you are trying to do?
http://dabblet.com/gist/2492793

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
.logo{
     float:left;
     width: 86px;
     height:98px;
     display:block;    
}

.img2{
    float:right;
    display:block;
}

.clear{
    clear:both;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="title">
        <h1>
            <img class="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="" />
            <a href="index.html">Page Header Title</a>
            <img class="img2" src="images/img2.png" alt="" />
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

The reason the logo is dropping out of the div is because it is not cleared.
This should fix things up.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#logo{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo">
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/853168/pexels-photo-853168.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260" alt="something" width="100" height="100"/>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
</div>
```